# How do i make that it will say the text to speech only once by logic ?

Tags: java, c#, .net, winforms

On the pc in c# this is the webserver i have this part:

```
private void cases()
{
    if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
                    {
                        switch (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus)
                        {
                            case "uploading file":
                                return "uploading";

                            case "file uploaded successfully":
                                Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                                return "upload completed";

                            default:
                                return "upload unknown state";
                        }
                    }
}
```

Then i have in the client side the java using android studio this code:

```
Runnable serverChecksRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (connectedSuccess == true)
            {

                checkServer = Get(iptouse + "uploadstatus");

            }

            Handler h=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            h.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (connectedSuccess)
                    {
                        if (checkServer != null)
                        {
                            String a = null;
                            try
                            {
                                a = new String(checkServer, "UTF-8");
                                textforthespeacch = a;
                                if (textforthespeacch.equals("upload completed"))
                                    MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                if (textforthespeacch.equals("uploading"))
                                {
                                    servercheckCounter += 1;
                                    if (servercheckCounter == 1)
                                    {
                                        MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                    }
                                }


                                servercheckCounter = 0;
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            customHandler.postDelayed(serverChecksRunnable,1000);
        }
    };
```

This line send a command to the webserver every second:

```
checkServer = Get(iptouse + "uploadstatus");
```

Back to the pc this is the working part: The webserver when i the case is "file uploaded successfully" i then reset the variable Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = ""; to be empty string the result is that it will say  return "upload completed"; only once.

The problem is while it's uploading.
When the case is: "uploading file" on the webserver it keep saying every second "uploading" but i want that it will say "uploading" also only once.

I tried to do also to reset the variable like this:

```
                        case "uploading file":
                        Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                        return "uploading";
```

But it keep saying "uploading" every second.
I tried in the java the client side code to make some checkings:

```
if (textforthespeacch.equals("upload completed"))
                                    MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                if (textforthespeacch.equals("uploading"))
                                {
                                    servercheckCounter += 1;
                                    //if (servercheckCounter == 10)
                                    //{
                                    if (servercheckCounter == 1)
                                    {
                                        MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                    }

                                    //  servercheckCounter = 0;
                                    //}
                                }
```

So if the it's completed it's working fine saying only once.
But when it's uploading it's saying "uploading" every second.

Another problem might be is the first time i wanted it to say "uploading" every 10 seconds but the webserver might be uploading it before a 10 seconds passed.

So i can't find the right logic and also how to make it work.
I think i want to make it so it will say each status once:

"uploading"

"upload completed"

But i can't make it work saying each status case once only.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is simply to keep a boolean status that tells whether the "uploading" has already been said. You make sure to reset that status to `false` when starting an upload, and then, whenever an "uploading" status arrives, you check the boolean. Something like this:

```
private Boolean uploadAnnounceDone = false;

private void checkUpload()
{
    String status = cases();
    if (status.Equals("uploading"))
    {
        if (!uploadAnnounceDone)
        {
            uploadAnnounceDone = true;
            PlayVoice(status);
        }
    }
    else
        PlayVoice(status);
}
```

If you reuse this same setup for multiple uploads, make sure to reset the boolean back to False when starting another upload, though.

Note that currently, your code is invalid; the "cases()" function should return that string. You set its return type to `void`